# Variable not updating properly within if statement - Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a tool to grade power tools. I'm trying to make it so that when you update a select element, it checks the value of the current option and disables and enables certain elements around it. 
The problem I'm running into is that my if statement I'm using does not update the value and gets stuck on the default option.

The code I am using:

Html

```
<select class='form-control garDropdown' id='garDropdown' name='gar'>
<option value='goedgekeurd'>Goedgekeurd</option>
<option value='reparatie'>Na reparatie goedgekeurd</option>
<option value='afgekeurd'>Afgekeurd</option></select>
```

js

```
$(document).on('change', '.garDropdown', function(){
var e = document.getElementById("garDropdown");
var y = e.value;
    console.log(y);
    if (y = "goedgekeurd"){
      $('.repverText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.afkeurText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.toelichtText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.ipwText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      console.log(y)
    } else if (y = "reparatie") {
      $('.repverText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.afkeurText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.toelichtText').prop('disabled', false);
      $('.ipwText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      console.log(y)
    } else if (y = "afgekeurd"){
      $('.repverText').prop('disabled', false);
      $('.afkeurText').prop('disabled', false);
      $('.toelichtText').prop('disabled', false);
      $('.ipwText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      console.log(y)
}
});
```

The initial console.log(y) prints the correct value but the console.log(y) within the statement constantly prints 'goedgekeurd'. What am I looking past and is this even possible in this format or am I completely f***ing this up in the first place?

Thanks!

EDIT: Forgot a line of JS code

Comment: You need to use `==` not `=` it will always get caught in the first statement because the statement `y = "goedgekeurd"` will always yield true as you are assigning `"goedgekeurd"` to `y` :)

Comment: I believe your `if` statement is not properly written. A single `=` sign basically means assignment of variables.

Comment: @Alex That worked! Silly mistake, should know that haha. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BlackRose00101 no problem, its early in the morning :P I posted an answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently testing if the assignment of `y = "goedgekeurd"` is true which it always will be, this assignment will never fail and therefore you will always trigger the first if statement.

You need to use an equality operator opposed to an assignment operator, therefore:
`if( y == "goedgekeurd" )` would check if the value you passed is the same.  Alternatively you could use `===` to check for the value and type of the object you're comparing, for example `1 == "1"` is true but `1 === "1"` is false because the left side is an in and the right hand side is a string.

Solution:

```
$(document).on('change', '.garDropdown', function(){
var e = document.getElementById("garDropdown");
var y = e.value;
console.log(y);
if (y === "goedgekeurd"){
    $('.repverText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.afkeurText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.toelichtText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.ipwText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    console.log(y)
} else if (y === "reparatie") {
    $('.repverText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.afkeurText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.toelichtText').prop('disabled', false);
    $('.ipwText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    console.log(y)
} else if (y === "afgekeurd"){
    $('.repverText').prop('disabled', false);
    $('.afkeurText').prop('disabled', false);
    $('.toelichtText').prop('disabled', false);
    $('.ipwText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    console.log(y)
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change', '.garDropdown', function(){
var e = document.getElementById("garDropdown");
var y = e.value;
    console.log(y);
    if (y === "goedgekeurd"){
      $('.repverText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.afkeurText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.toelichtText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.ipwText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      console.log(y)
    } else if (y === "reparatie") {
      $('.repverText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.afkeurText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.toelichtText').prop('disabled', false);
      $('.ipwText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      console.log(y)
    } else if (y === "afgekeurd"){
      $('.repverText').prop('disabled', false);
      $('.afkeurText').prop('disabled', false);
      $('.toelichtText').prop('disabled', false);
      $('.ipwText').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      console.log(y)
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of if statement is wrong, this is an assignment statement and will always remain true. Always execute if statement

If statement should be like that

```
if (y == "goedgekeurd"){
//Do something here
}
else if (y == "reparatie") {
//Do something here
}
else if (y == "afgekeurd"){
//Do something here
}
```

Comment: @BlackRose00101 Try it. Hope this will work for you.